# Clear WKWebView history to avoid going back and forward in browsing history

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, wkwebview, browser-history

I'm using the newest version of `Xcode` and `Swift`.

I'm using a `WKWebView` to load content from my web server.

You can swipe to go back and forward in the history of web pages you visited.

There's also a button to go back to the home page.

I additionally want to clear the history/`backForwardList`, so it's impossible to go back or forward, since this is the expected behavior when you `reset` the current view.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As such, there is no method defined by Apple to do so but if you really wish to implement this functionality, I would suggest you just reinitialize your WKWebView.

webView = WKWebView()

I did this in my app but one thing to note is that you will have to reset all your constraints again.